# How To Pass a Dictionary Of Labels and Values into jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-views, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to pass in a dictionary of Labels and Values into my template so that I can use the autocomplete on one of my fields with jQuery. The problem is that my dictionary is not being passed in correctly.

I have a Django model `Question` that has a question (label) and a slug (value). I want to pass both of these into my template so that when someone clicks on the question text, I can redirect them to the url/slug of that question.

**Question.html**

```
<input id="search-bar" name="question" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find your next question..." aria-label="Find your next question...">

<div class="input-group-append">
    <button id="search-question-button" class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("[name='question']").autocomplete({
            source: "{% url 'questions' slug=question.slug %}",
            select: function (event, ui) {
                window.location.href = ui.item.value;
                console.log(ui.item);
                
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Views.py**

```
if 'term' in request.GET:
    qs = current_questions.filter(question__istartswith=request.GET.get('term'))
    qs_dict = dict()

    for question in qs:
        qs_dict['label'] = question.question
        qs_dict['value'] = question.slug
    print(qs_dict)

    return JsonResponse(qs_dict, safe=False)
```

In my django project console I am printing this dictionary and it seems to be printing correctly `{'question': "Blah blah blah", 'slug': 'blah-blah-blah'}`

However, when I inspect my site using chrome I see that the label and value are the same and my dictionary did not get passed in correctly.

***EDIT:***

So now I am passing in a list of query sets:

**Views.py**

```
if 'term' in request.GET:
    qs = current_questions.filter(question__istartswith=request.GET.get('term'))
    qs_list = []

    for question in qs:
        qs_list.append(qs.values('question', 'slug'))

    return JsonResponse(qs_list, safe=False)
```

But I am getting the error `TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable`.

Also, does this mean that I have to change my keys from 'question' and 'slug' to 'label' and 'value'?

Comment: Autocomplete is expecting an Array of Objects: `[ { "label": "Apple", "value": "seed" }, { "label": "Peach", "value": "pit" } ]`  So if you're only passing back an Object, it will throw an error.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Please take a look at the edit I made.

Comment: You do not need to change the keys, but if you can, it will be helpful. Autocomplete will not be looking for those keys, so you either have to change them in py or in js.